# Getting a vector::reverse_iterator from a vector::iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have problem iterating over and `std::vector`. I'm iterating with a `std::vector::iterator` in a while loop, and at some point into my loop, I want a `std::vector::reverse_iterator` that points to the same element than the `iterator`. But I can't figure out how to get it right.

Here's a snippet to help you understand my problem. Here, for example, I have the `tab` vector containing (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), and I want to print out something like :

```
1
21
321
4321
54321
654321
7654321
```

Here's the code I'm thinking of in the first place to achieve this:

```
std::vector<int> tab {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; // C++11 needed here, if I recall correctly

for(std::vector<int>::iterator i(tab.begin()) ; i != tab.end() ; ++i) {
    for(std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator j(/* ? */) ; j != tab.rend() ; ++j) {
        std::cout << *j;
    }
std::cout << std::endl;
```

I hope my question is clear, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: `std::vector<int>::reverse iterator j{i+1}`

Comment: Sorry for the dupe, I didn't know what I was looking for exactly, so I didn't find anything. :(

And thanks for the answers, very precise and swift, as always! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a reverse iterator from an iterator.  The important thing to remember is that when you do that it goes back one element when doing so.  If you do:

```
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator rit(foo.begin());
```

`foo.begin` points at the first element where `rit` will point to one before the first element.  With that you for loop could become

```
std::vector<int> tab {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; // C++11 needed here, if I recall correctly

for(std::vector<int>::iterator i(tab.begin()) ; i != tab.end() ; ++i) {
    for(std::vector<int>::reverse iterator j(i + 1) ; j != tab.rend() ; ++j) {
        std::cout << *j;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How would I do the same with an affectation instead of a declaration?

Comment: What do you mean by affectation?

Answer (score 1):

Given a pair of arbitrary iterators like `tab.begin()` and `i`, you can reverse them by using `std::reverse_iterator`, vaguely like so:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator i(tab.begin()) ; i != tab.end() ; ++i) {
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator> riterator;
    riterator start = riterator(i); //start toward the back-ish
    riterator stop = riterator(tab.begin()) //stop at the front
    for(riterator j=start; j!=stop; ++j) 
        std::cout << *j;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator j{i+1};
```

Reverse iterators of always have a "base", an instance of the base iterator. I'm not sure the reasoning, but they wanted this base instance to have the same end points, i.e. `v.begin()==v.rend(), v.end()==v.rbegin()`. This means that in order to get an iterator pointing to the same end point, you have an offset of one:

```
v.begin()+10==
v.rend()-10-1==
reverse_iterator(v.begin()+10+1)==
reverse_iterator(v.begin()+10)-1
```